# Java - Defining line for creating objects instead of working only with methods

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, static-methods

There' a question that's been bothering me:

What is the defining line for using methods, instead of a using objects, if methods could solve the same problem ?

for example: a program that does average to complex computations.

Is working with objects more expensive than with methods ?
Thank you all,

Comment: No. You misunderstand OO programming completely. It's not one or the other.

Comment: This question dose not deserve up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​You are thinking about procedural programming where is you call one method after another. Object oriented programming brings more structure to your program e.g [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29), [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and much more.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the defining line for using methods, instead of a using objects, if methods could solve the same problem ?

Methods alone do not solve *the problem*. I think you really like [functional programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17976/how-many-types-of-programming-languages-are-there).

> for example: a program that does average to complex computations.

That isn't a very good example. It's too abstract. But yes, some *average* algorithms can be implemented with few or one method(s).

> Is working with objects more expensive than with methods ?

Again, this doesn't make any sense. You require [some basic knowledge of OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), and then you will answer this question yourself.

It is fine to ask such questions, but you have to do your research and be more specific with your question (at least on StackOverflow). These types of questions usually get downvoted/closed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question heavily sounds like you are more into procedural/functional programming style. When you have subroutines/ routines (we call it as functions/methods in application programming languages) even in scripting languages then why should you consider some application programming languages?

There is a concept called **ADT** (Abstract data Type) ***which is the foundation for classes in OOPs languages***. ADT **defines** set of data and set of related operations to process the data. Here only **encapsulation** comes into the picture to abstract your data to external entities to ensure the object consistent and data hiding. And it proposes “***Achieve a state only through the action***”. I personally recommend you to understand what is OOP and why OOPs.

Cheers!